# How to cast an int larger than 127 to a byte in Clojure

Tags: java, python, clojure, byte, twos-complement

The byte `0xea` is equal to 234 in base 10. In Python, bytes are represented using unsigned integers, but in Java, they are [signed, two's complement integers](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).

For example, in Java, if I cast `(byte)234`, I get the signed integer `-22`. When I use those bytes in a `MessageDigest`, I get the same exact hash output as when I use the unsigned `234` in python. So I am confident that these represent the same byte.

However, in Clojure, the function `(byte 234)` should cast to `-22`, but instead it throws a `clojure.lang.RT.byteCast` exception.

How can I cast integers to bytes in Clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`unchecked-byte`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/unchecked-byte) when it's OK to overflow:

```
(unchecked-byte 234)
=> -22
```

FYI it's also possible to toggle the default behavior with the [`*unchecked-math*`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*unchecked-math*) binding:

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)
=> true
(byte 234)
=> -22
```

But you probably want to constrain this non-default behavior to the smallest scope possible.